# Data Reading Performance Optimizations

Tags: c, endianness

The goal is to read from a file one RECORD at a time. Each record is 16 bytes. The code below reads from the file one ELEMENT at a time. How can I change the fread() to read all 16 bytes at once?

GOAL: Reads data from disk one record at a time (16 bytes from disk in a single fread() call), and then splits it up into individual elements.

```
//Original unoptimized code to read one ELEMENT at a time
// Read the file in a naive way:
// One data item at a time!
struct record read_record_naive(FILE *fp, int endian)
{
  struct record my_data = {0,0,0,0,0};
  int result;
  uint8_t empty=0;

  my_data.valid = 1;
  result = fread(&(my_data.my8), sizeof(my_data.my8), 1, fp);
  if(!result)
    {
      my_data.valid = 0;
      return my_data;
    }

  result = fread(&(empty), sizeof(empty), 1, fp);
  if(!result)
    {
      my_data.valid = 0;
      return my_data;
    }

  result = fread(&(my_data.my16), sizeof(my_data.my16), 1, fp);
  if(!result)
    {
      my_data.valid = 0;
      return my_data;
    }

  result = fread(&(my_data.my32), sizeof(my_data.my32), 1, fp);
  if(!result)
    {
      my_data.valid = 0;
      return my_data;
    }

  result = fread(&(my_data.my64), sizeof(my_data.my64), 1, fp);
  if(!result)
    {
      my_data.valid = 0;
      return my_data;
    }

  if(endian == ENDIAN_LITTLE)
    record_swap_endian(&my_data);

  return my_data;
}
```

Comment: If you are writing whole data structure in to file then you should simply do as per @Serge Ballesta answer, But if you have data with different different entities then you need to take it out 1 by 1 as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

What about simply :

```
result = fread(&my_data), sizeof(my_data), 1, fp);
```

Is it not enough ?